# Oracle SQL - CASE WHEN THEN ELSE ignoring ELSE part

Tags: sql, oracle, case

i have a problem with my sql query and dont know how to solve it:

The output table consists of.

```
1. SERIALNR   VARCHAR(26) NOT NULL
2. LP_BASIC   VARCHAR(20) NOT NULL
3. LP_NEW     VARCHAR(20)
4. SCORE      NUMBER(20)  NOT NULL
5. CURRENT_LP VARCHAR(20)
```

The query itself works well and contains no errors.

The **LP_BASIC** column is always filled whereas the **LP_NEW** is an optional field.
**CURRENT_LP** should always display **LP_NEW** (if is not empty) else **LP_BASIC** (which is never empty).

The problem is, that the "**ELSE f.LP_BASIC**"-Part is not working.
It should return the **LP_BASIC value**, if no **LP_NEW** record is found but instead it only returns an empty field.

```
SELECT 
  f.SERIALNR,
  f.LP_BASIC,
  f.LP_NEW, 
  f.SCORE,
  CASE
    WHEN
      f.LP_NEW
      IS NOT NULL
        THEN
          f.LP_NEW
    ELSE
      f.LP_BASIC
  END
AS CURRENT_LP 
FROM (
        SELECT 
          SERIALNR, 
          MAX(SCORE) MAX_ID
        FROM 
          EAPS.PS_TC_SM 
        GROUP BY 
          SERIALNR
     ) x 
INNER JOIN 
  EAPS.PS_TC_SM f 
ON 
  f.SERIALNR=
  x.SERIALNR 
AND 
  f.SCORE = 
  x.MAX_ID
```

Any help apreciated.

Thank you in advance.

Rob.

**UPDATE** (solved)

The LP_NEW column was not null, there was a single space char in it, so the "IS NULL" did not work.

Comment: Please post some sample data, needed result and what you are getting from your query

Comment: wouldn't this be much simpler to read? `coalesce(f.LP_NEW ,f.LP_BASIC)`

Comment: @Kritner `Coalesce` is better. `Nvl` compares both values, `coalesce` stops as soon as a value is found.

Comment: @JohnHC ah thanks, I'm a SQL Server guy, i just looked for an "isnull" equivilant... which i find much simpler to read than a multi line case

Comment: Are you certain lp_new is actually null, and doesn't have a blank in it?

Comment: I am inclined to agree with DCookie, and predict that neither `NVL()` nor `COALESCE()` will solve the problem. It would be very weird if `NVL()` or `COALESCE()` would fix anything `CASE` does wrong, since they are logically equivalent - with the difference in implementation that makes `CASE` and `COALESCE()` a little faster than `NVL()` in some cases.

Comment: @DCookie Wow, i would have never thought it, but this was the problem! I am kind of new to SQL and we work qith SQL Developer, and i did some tests with IS EMPTY and = '' too, but = ' ' was never in my mind. thank you!

Answer (score 2):

(This was too long for a comment, therefore posted as an answer)

As already mentioned in the comments, your `CASE` statement is perfectly fine; you should re-check your input data.

Example that demonstrates the correctness of your approach with fake data:

```
with v_input(serialnr, lp_basic, lp_new) as (
  select 
    level, 
    'basic_' || to_char(level), 
    (case when mod(level, 2) = 0 then 'new_' || to_char(level) else null end)
  from dual
  connect by level <= 10)
SELECT 
  f.SERIALNR,
  f.LP_BASIC,
  f.LP_NEW, 
  CASE
    WHEN
      f.LP_NEW
      IS NOT NULL
        THEN
          f.LP_NEW
    ELSE
      f.LP_BASIC
  END
AS CURRENT_LP 
FROM v_input f
```

Comment: Thank you. There was a single space char in all LP_NEW records that prevented the CASE statement to work so i changed the IS NULL to = ' ' and now the whole thing works as expected. Im kind of new to sql and did not thought about this could happen.

Answer (score -1):

Try using the oracle NVL function instead, essentially it will select the value specified, if it is null, then it will select the secondary value.

```
SELECT NVL(LP_NEW,LP_BASIC)
```

https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B19306_01/server.102/b14200/functions105.htm

Comment: That is totally equivalent to the `CASE` approach and doesn't solve the OP's problem.